# Shell script to print system.log file from past hour

Tags: macos, bash, shell, awk

I'm trying to read the system.log file on Mac OS X for all records in the past hour. I've searched other questions which have been asked on here but none of their solutions are working for me, possibly due to being on Mac OS X?

I'm able to read the system.log file for all records listed between the two date/times in the code below, using an `awk` command. Then write this to a text file and read its contents for further analysis.

```
awk '$0 >= "Nov 11 09:15:00" && $0 <= "Nov 11 10:15:00"' /var/log/system.log > newfile.txt
```

However I would like to be able to make the time an automatic calculation using the current time, and current time - 1 hour.

I have been able to show the current time and current time - 1 hour using this code.

```
now=$(date +"%b %d %H:%M:%S")
hourago=$(date -v-60M "+%b %d %H:%M:%S")
```

But can't find a way of using this within the `awk` statement.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: In `awk`, you can use the `system()`, `strftime()` and `mktime()` functions. Read [this link](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?awk)

Answer (score 0):

Try something similar to this:

```
awk 'BEGIN {now=system("date +\"%b %d %H:%M:%S\"")}'
```

Comment: Thanks this works. I've also added code to show me current time - 1 hour:


`awk 'BEGIN {hour=system("date -v-60M +\"%b %d %H:%M:%S\"")}'`

Comment: @Tom You can use `-1h` instead of `-60m`

Comment: Of course that makes a lot of sense. Now that I have these two times, do I need to store them as a variable and call them into my awk statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
awk 'BEGIN {now=strftime("%b %d %T")}'
```

`%T` is a shortcut for `%H:%M:%S`

Comment: I'm seeing an error message that `strftime` is an undefined function. Thanks for the tip of `%T`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not know the insights of Mac OS X. I assumed the `awk` version on Mac OS X was the same than Linux one. Test yourself if `%T` works fine on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strftime` to print the current time. and a combination of `strftime` and `systime` to obtiain previous hour

eg usage

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {now=strftime("%b %d %T");hourago=strftime("%b %d %T", systime()-3600); print now, hourago}'
Nov 11 19:11:22 Nov 11 18:11:22
```

**What it does??**

- `systime()-3600` the `systime()` prints the number of seconds elapsed since Epoch. `-3600` reduces an hour from that. The `strftime` returns the time corresopding to that seconds, that is 1 hour less than the current time, `now`

Comment: Thanks. It seems that `strftime()` isn't support as it shows as an undefined function. But I have adapted the code to use `system()` instead, which works. It also prints two zero's after the times, why would that be?

Comment: @Tom The zeros you see are the exit status of commands given inside `system` Now the problem with `system` is that you cannot get the output of the command to a variable. It just excecutes the commands. That is referring to the A.M.D's answer the `now` variable will contain `0` and not time. which is the exit status of the date command

Comment: @Tom `strftime()` GNU gawk extension. instead of using `awk` you can use `gawk` which would work fine with the above script in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for this info. It seems that `gawk` doesn't work either, as I am seeing "command not found" error.

Comment: @Tom by default Osx does not provide `gawk` you can download and install that